# Need to delete a couple of characters from one column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have tried various things to remove just the the **Call** ,**[**,**]** and **'** from column D. What am I missing?

[image: excel copy/paste]

I've tried:

```
.str.replace

df.Required_no_Email.replace("\(", 'xxx', regex=True)

df.Required_no_Email.replace('\(|\)', '', regex=True)

df.Required_no_Email.str.strip('()')
```

and quite a few others, but I have lost track of what else I've tried.

Here's the script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd


URL = 'https://reallyfrustrated.com'
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')


business = soup.find('title')
companys = business.get_text()


phones = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Call (.*)"))



data = {'Required':[companys], 'Required_no_Email':[phones]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Required','First', 'Last', 'Required_no_Email', 'Business Fax'])



writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ProspectUploadSheetRob.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=4, header=3)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': False,
    'text_wrap': False,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': False,
    'border': False})


for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(4, col_num, value, header_format)

df.Required_no_Email.str.strip('()')

writer.save()
```

Comment: hey Rob, can you share the sample data from your image as text?

Comment: CTC Landscaping 
['Call (440) 840-6739']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RobK the below works with a one-liner for whatever characters you want to replace. You were pretty close in one of your tries above passing **regex=True** and **escaping characters** with \ and using an or separator with **|**. You need to remember to set the changes with df.Required_no_Email =.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Required' : ['CTC Landscaping'],
                   'Required_no_Email' : ['''['Call (123) 456-7890']''']})
df.Required_no_Email = df.Required_no_Email.replace('\[|\]|\'|\(|\)', '', 
                                                    regex=True)
df
```

@RobK you said your code was not changing anything. My guess is that you placed the replace part of your script after creating the writer object. It is working for me below. I created my own dataframe in place of the beautiful soup portion of your code, and it worked perfectly. I will also attach a screenshot:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Required' : ['CTC Landscaping'],
'Required_no_Email' : ['''['Call (123) 456-7890']''']})
df.Required_no_Email = df.Required_no_Email.replace('\[|\]|\'|\(|\)', '', 
                                                    regex=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ProspectUploadSheetRob.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')


df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=4, header=3)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': False,
    'text_wrap': False,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': False,
    'border': False})


for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(4, col_num, value, header_format)

df.Required_no_Email.str.strip('()')

writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David.  The first option you threw up there works, which is awesome!, and i think it's because it creates the df in and of itself.  But, if i take the second option and throw it in my script, it prints to terminal and to my xlsx file like above.  Sooo confused.

Comment: Perfect RobK, since you wanted to set the changes to the column, I'll take the second inplace=True  part out of my answer, if you can mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: David, any thoughts as to why it won't work in my actual script?  Since it works on it's own, it means that I've screwed up else where in my script.

Comment: lol...that's the thing..it's not.  It runs to completion, but gives the original output CTC Landscaping ['Call (440) 840-6739'].

Comment: RobK, see my edited answer. That should do it... please also upvote my post if helpful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209228/discussion-between-david-erickson-and-robk).